# How are MacOS Terminal settings backed up in iCloud?

Tags: macos, terminal, icloud, high-sierra

I wonder if anyone has managed to find out any Apple documentation that details how macOS terminal settings are stored in iCloud and then propagate across new machines as soon as you sign into iCloud. I just jumped on a new MacBook Pro, and found that my tcsh preference magically appeared in terminal (I hadn't changed a thing, bash is the OS default).

Comment: Are you sure they do? In my past experience this hasn't been the case, but I'm willing to test again. Did you use Migration Assistant or anything?

Comment: I was really surprised, but yes it seemed that my shell was set to tcsh (not bash, the default) and some other weird tweaks. I was a little surprised to be honest, and couldn't find anywhere to document the experience that I had